# HTML Based Phone Apps More Acceptable on Android than IOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a children's book app which is 'done' on IOS.  It is a fully native app.

In the past I have considered using a HTML based framework to support Android and other platforms quickly but have always opted out.  Long story short, I think most (not all) of those apps are easy to pick out and just don't feel right on IOS.

For some reason I feel like the apps built on Android using something like Phonegap might not feel so out of place.  Is it a more common practice on Android than IOS to take the HTML route?

Comment: Flagged as there's no explicit answer to this question.

Comment: In general, HTML5 apps feel out of place on any platform. Conversely, you could expend a great deal of effort to create a well-performing HTML app that properly implements the unique conventions of the target platform.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an opinion based on personal experience and minor references.

> Is it a more common practice on Android than IOS to take the HTML route?

Empirically I don't know, my gut feeling is no. Even if the answer was yes, it certainly doesn't prove that web apps are more "acceptable" on Android than iOS.

As an Android engineer, I'm biased towards building native apps rather than web apps. But I've worked on both types of apps, and not only are native apps more satisfying to build, they're also more immensely satisfying to use.

> I think most (not all) of those apps are easy to pick out

Yes. Unless an extraordinary amount of care is put into the web app, it's easily distinguishable from a native app. They've slower UX, generally lack the UI richness provided by the Android framework and can't leverage many of the native features. But this isn't to say it may not be right for you. You'll find advocates of both approaches. Facebook and Netflix famously moved from a web-app/hybrid-app to an all-native app with great success, while web-app proponents claim that web apps do have the potential to be great (see Sencha's example of [Facebook web-app here](http://fb.html5isready.com/)).

My suggestion to you is this: The end user doesn't care what technologies you use to build your app, and both approaches have their implementation challenges. It boils down to how your app makes them feel, and as of today I haven't experienced a web app that has made me feel better than a counterpart native app.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I suspect that I will end up taking the native approach as much as I'd love a shortcut.  I can easily see spending the time saved in using something like PhoneGap just trying to make the app feel more natural.

Comment: Yes, the time savings of making a webapp are questionable. You may also want to learn the difference between native-compiled apps and web apps. Both are written using web technologies, but some tools compile the code into native code which improves performance and are closer to all-native apps. Although I wouldn't personally recommend it, you may want to looks at what tools like Xamarin do.

Comment: I love in principal what Xamarin does but having to build out the UIs entirely in code in an abstraction of the Apple / Android APIs seems like asking for agony.  I wish I could just use Xamarin to create my core libraries and build everything else natively but that doesn't seem to exist.  Right?